# wpf datagrid styling

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, styles, styling

I'm using a DataGrid to print out an invoice in my application, but it doesn't look good at all, I don't like a scrollbar on paper for instance, it doesn't work on paper, can anyone point me in the right direction to style my datagrid?

Right now, it look something like [this](http://hhreviews.com/ScreenShot001.bmp), but it should look like [this](http://hhreviews.com/afb.jpg), well, not exactly, but it should look like a table, I'm sure you get the point.

Answer (score 0):

well, i don't think the most controls are designed to use them for printing. i'd use ms office interop to fill a word or excel "template" and print from there ... additional advantage: you don't need a developer to make changes to a word file that's used as template ... a secretary can do that

but if you want to do this with a `DataGridView` ... here's what i would try (sorry ... winforms ... maybe you have to figure out what to change for a WPF project)

the scroll bar is visible because the controls current size doesn't allow all column space to be drawn -> the total width of all columns is too big -> try seting the DGVs `AutoSizeColumnsMode` to `DisplayedCells` and the first columns `AutoSizeMode` to `Fill`

for the other visual aspects:

```
dataGridView.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None;
dataGridView.CellBorderStyle = DataGridViewCellBorderStyle.SingleVertical;
dataGridView.EnableHeadersVisualStyles = false;

ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle.Font = new Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 9.75F, FontStyle.Bold, GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Black;
ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle.SelectionBackColor = Color.White;
ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle.SelectionForeColor = Color.Black;
```